# how to parse datetime according to host datetime format

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, parsing, datetime

I having a major issue in my project regarding datetime. the user gives the input for date or sometimes i get the date from my database according to the project requiremnt. but the format given by user is different if they insert manually and the date format which i get from the database is different from different servers. To bring the datetime in one format i used this method `tryParseExact()` in development it runs properly but in production it fails also the production datetime format is different so sometimes it parse and sometimes it takes wrong dateformat like instead of taking dd/MM/yyyy it takes MM/dd/yyyy. I have added the code snippet for parseing the date time.

```
SqlParameter StartingDateParam=null;
DateTime mdate=null;
string idate = GetEffectiveFromDate();//retriving date from database

string[] formats = new[] { "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"};

string sysFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.;//getting the host datetime format

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(idate, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out mdate))
{ 
    StartingDateParam = new SqlParameter("@startingdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    StartingDateParam.Value = mdate;
}
```

here one issue was with sequence of formats given in the formats array, second i have to add all types of datetime formats in the array depending upon the user input.
Please help to get unified solution.

Comment: Try changing `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` into `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Comment: no still it is not working.

Comment: Can you give us an example date where it fails pasing?

Comment: Sometimes it take the system date format. I faced the similar issue. Try to save the date in the unique format always in the database, so that it will be easier for retrieving.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is impossible!

Just imagine a user's input of `07/04/2017` (today's date in `dd/MM/yyyy`). You **cannot know** if this is the 7th of April or the 4th of July!

This would get even worse, if users are allowed to enter the year in two digits!

And it gets still worse, if users are allowed to type in parts as words (e.g. `7 apr 2017`.

Clear advise: Use a date-picker control instead of the text input. At least do the conversion in your application and **present the converted date** to the user. At the moment, when your code deals with the values, the validation/conversion has to be done already...

Comment: Ok for user i can restrict them to particular format but what about host format it changes in production and when i use `datetime.now` it gives different format for each user. how to parse those formats?

Comment: @abhishek `DateTime.Now` does not have any format, is a date. If you are   doing `ToString` on `DateTime.Now` to save the value to the database as string, use always `InvariantCulture` like this: `DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. This way the format would be consistent no matter the culture in the client

Comment: @abhishek - `DateTime.Now` *doesn't* produce different formats. It produces a `DateTime`, which internally just stores the number of 100ns intervals since 01/01/0001. Your problems arise when you convert `DateTime`s to *strings*. So avoid that as much as possible (take input from user, convert to `DateTime` and only convert back into a string when *presenting* it back to the user)

Comment: @abhishek As told by others, your are mixing the date's value and its textual representation. You should **never rely on system's culture settings** nor on any date/time format which is culture/language depending.

Comment: I have one question if machine format is in MM/dd/yyyy and user input is in dd/MM/yyyy format then will i get exception if i try to convert using `Convert.ToDateTime()` it to datetime and store it in databse?

Comment: @abhishek yes with 13/4/2017, not with 12/3/2017, but the second would be tanken as 3rd of December. Just don't rely in this !

Comment: @abhishek Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!